# Watson Studio -- Error Downloading Desktop Version

Tags: data-science-experience, watson-studio

Downloading the Watson Studio for desktop (to a Windows 7 machine) from [here](https://datascience.ibm.com/desktop), and selecting only RStudio, I get the message "There was an error extracting the image. Please try again later."  I've made several attempts over 2 days. Any help/advice please on the likely cause/solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked after temporarily disabling the firewall.